# Migrate application lotus notes to C #

Tags: c#, database, migration, mask, lotus

Hello everyone and thank you in advance,

I am currently working on a new project for a client, the goal is simple, but I need an idea.

The client have multiple databases lotus (oriented application) it would transformed those in client server platform C #. NET with a SQL Server database.

He no longer wishes to have the license for Lotus Notes it's unprofitable for his company.

There are tools to migrate database on sharepoint but the purpose here is different because the handling is manual.

Can you tell me the steps to do? :)

I have 3 years experience in Lotus Notes.

I think creating ACL rules with user and group sessions table type admin, player, modifcator ect ....

The mask will be the template of the website.

But the creation of the database, I think extract data to a CSV file and import it into the database.

I do not know whether they should put the unique identifier of a document or single digit.

If someone already has manually migrate some database lotus and have a little time to explain how he did it.

Thank you all for taking the time to read and all is good to take suggestions.

I'll have a total of 60 applications to migrate.

Comment: if possible can you translate in english

Comment: Hi, please use english on StackOverflow. See non-english question policy: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: @madbay do you mind if I edit your post to add an english version?

Comment: @tijizor I have a pending edit with the post put thru Google translate.

Comment: @tijizor Hi you can translate because my english it's not really great

Comment: @madbay it wasn't me ! The edit was done before I had time to translate it all.

Answer (score 1):

You better have a good concept for doing this.

First of all you need to have generic / configurable code to export the content of the documents to any format that you can put into an SQL- database. 
This is not a big deal for summary- data (Text- , Date- , Name- , Number- items), but will be complicated for Richtextitems (Formatted text, attachments, embedded images, etc...).

Best suggestion is to buy a product that does this export for you because unless you are a very experienced LotusScript Programmer you will not get "good" Richtext- data out of Lotus Notes.

The next step will be to analyze the functionality and rewrite that as an C#- Application. 
I hope, the applications are all similar and do not use complex business- logic. Otherwise you will still write code at the end of this year (and not be finished until then).

Better estimate up to 100 days of work for all of this to be completed...